# cake php can't read the url correctly

Tags: php, cakephp, url-rewriting, debian

I just bought a new dedicated server to make my website inside

My website is created with cake php and the server debian

as I look at my site www.exemple. com it get me out the html css and flow but the images are not displayed 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://exemple.com/img/logo.png

the file exists in / webroot / img /

the site is http://proveille.com

Comment: check whether mod_rewrite is enabled ?

Comment: how I can check it ? in unix ?

Comment: if it's apache try phpinfo() and look in the output if there is mod_rewrite in "Loaded Modules" section

Comment: mod_rewrite exists in "Loaded Modules"

Comment: In this case, check if all premissions for directories are correct

Comment: Can you load js properly? Or they also fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 1. Make sure that an .htaccess override is allowed and that
    AllowOverride is set to All for the correct DocumentRoot.
 2. Make sure you are loading mod_rewrite correctly.
 3. Make sure your copy of CakePHP comes from the downloads section of
    the site or our Git repository, and has been unpacked correctly, by
    checking for .htaccess files.
```

For more details read the cookbook [page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html#apache-and-mod-rewrite-and-htaccess).

Answer (score 0):

Edit your .htaccess file inside /app for this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```